# save user instance to another model after post_save django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have to two models: CustomUser and Artist.
What I am trying to achieve is that, when i create a user it should automatically create an artist.
I don't want to add a OneToOne field in artist model. I just want to fill these fields: name, artist_category, artist_image and bio, using post_save when CustomUser is created.

## custom user model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     artist_choice = [
     (0, 'celebrities'),
     (1, 'singer'),
     (2, 'comedian'),
     (3, 'dancer'),
     (4, 'model'),
     (5, 'Photographer')

    ]
    artist_category = models.IntegerField(choices=artist_choice, null=True)
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    country = CountryField()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]

    objects=UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)


 class Artist(models.Model):
     CHOICES = (
       (0, 'celebrities'),
       (1, 'singer'),
       (2, 'comedian'),
       (3, 'dancer'),
       (4, 'model'),
       (5, 'Photographer')
              )

      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      artist_category = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES, null=True)
      artist_image = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'media',null=True)
      bio = models.TextField(max_length = 500)

      def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDITED**

Using [Django Signals Post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) will work so just add the values to artist table via a dict.

**Instance** is the data that is saved to the `CustomUser` model so you can 
get specific elements of data via accessing `instance` and create a dict with required data that can be passed to `Artist` model.

Try This:

```
def create_artist(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        data = {
                'name' : instance.name,
                'artist_category' : instance.artist_category,
                'bio' : instance.bio
               }
        Artist.objects.create(**data)
post_save.connect(create_artist, sender=CustomUser)
```

Comment: user not defined anywhere

Comment: Its because you need to create a dict like i did in edit above that is customized to save data according to your model.

Comment: i think its not instance.get because its looking for get object in CustomUser

Comment: check the edit, instance is the object containing data so you can directly access elements through it.

Comment: Happy To help:-)